# Passing json text as command line argument

Tags: python, json, powershell

I am trying to pass the following JSON text into my python code.

```
{"platform": "android", "version": "6.0.1"}
```

My code is as follows.

```
import sys
import json
data = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
print(str(data))
```

When running the following on Windows 10 PowerShell,

```
python jsonTest.py '{"platform": "android", "version": "6.0.1"}'
```

I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "jsonTest.py", line 3, in <module>
data = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
File "C:\Users\Rishabh Bhatnagar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "C:\Users\Rishabh Bhatnagar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "C:\Users\Rishabh Bhatnagar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double 
quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

As far as I know, I take my code, and pass the JSON text properly. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I know the JSON text is valid (checked with https://jsonlint.com/). Thanks.

Comment: Try not adding quotes in the command line argument

Comment: Just tried it, gives unexpected token error.

Comment: Check out my solution below

Comment: Are you sure you used PowerShell, and not a regular command prompt or something? Can you show a raw copy-paste of your PowerShell session, from the line where you run the script to the end of all error output?

Comment: @user2357112 Actually it works on a normal terminal. Dunno if it makes a difference, I'm running on zsh.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: What, zsh on Windows? I'm talking about PowerShell vs the regular Windows command prompt.

Comment: Oop, windows didn't register.

Comment: Has to be something weird Windows is doing to command line arguments with special characters like `"`. Too bad I'm on Ubuntu.

Comment: Maybe you can try to escaping out the quotes like `\"` and enclose the whole argument in double quotes.

Answer (score 8):

So I figured it out.

```
sys.argv[1]
```

The above line was taking my Json text below and taking out the quotes from it.

```
{"platform": "android", "version": "6.0.1"}
```

into

```
{platform: android, version: 6.0.1}
```

My workaround is to run it as follows.

```
Python jsonTest.py '{\"platform\": \"android\", \"version\": \"6.0.1\"}'
```

I will try to find a better way, but for today, I'm done.

Comment: Yep, typical Windows headache.

Comment: That's annoying. Glad you got it sorted out

Comment: Thanks guys. Yeah that's total BS. I really hope this doesn't happen on osx, which is where this code will be running.

Comment: in windows use addslashes to the string

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys
import json
data = json.loads(sys.argv[1].replace("'", '"'))
print(str(data))
```

This seems to work for me, python 3.6 when calling with `python jsonTest.py "{'platform': 'android', 'version': '6.0.1'}"`

Comment: calling from powershell with the command and code posted, it does. Windows 7, python 3.6, powershell

Comment: Running 3.6.1, does not work for me. I will try to debug this and see where it takes me tho, thanks a lot.

Comment: hmm, weird. I'm running 3.6.0

Comment: @jacoblaw thanks, when I figure it out, I'll update here. Worst case tomorrow ill go try this on an actual linux based device and see if it works on that. As far as I know, what I have should work.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 11, Python 3.11:

```py
import json
import sys

cmdstr = dict(json.loads(sys.argv[1].replace("'", '"'))) 
print(json.dumps(cmdstr))
```

Input:

```
python test.py "{'First': 'foo', 'Second': 'bar', 'Third': 'baz'}"
```

Output:

```json
{"First": "foo", "Second": "bar", "Third": "baz"}
```

Bills box likes it.!